# Casting the sender of an event to find the value in a Dictionary that fired the event

Tags: c#, dictionary, .net-4.5

In my class, I have a private C# Dictionary where the key is a string, and the value is an object that has a `PropertyChanged` event. Defined as below:

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, IAlsVariable> m_operatorAudibleSevServerVariables = new Dictionary<string, IAlsVariable>();
```

In my constructor, I have the following foreach that populates the `Dictionary`:

```
        foreach (var clusterManager in clusterManagers)
        {
            var clusterName = clusterManager.Name;
            string opcDataSourceServer = "server/" + clusterName + ":[2:http://www.alstom.com/Transport/Iconis/S2K/Data]<Organizes>2:S2KServer<Organizes>2:S2KTerritoryMngt<Organizes>2:TASSObject<HasComponent>2:OperatorAudibleSev";
            var opcVariable = m_alsApplication.Database.GetVariable(opcDataSourceServer, null);
            opcVariable.PropertyChanged += OpcVariable_PropertyChanged;
            m_operatorAudibleSevServerVariables.Add(clusterManager.Name, opcVariable);                
        }
```

As you can see, before I add an instance of each variable (value) to the dictionary, I also subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event of each variable.

Now whenever one of the instances of the variables fires the `PropertyChanged` event, I execute the (one) event handler. The problem is that I do not know which of the variables in the dictionary fired the `PropertyChanged` event.

I have a method called `UpdateAlarmSound` that I need to call whenever this event fires. The first parameter I need to pass to this method is the key of the related variable from the dictionary.

My first guess is to cast the variable and then use that value to search for the key. But I do not know if this is the reliable way to do this. The code below is what I have. It seems to be working, but I have some doubts that maybe there is another better way. Or maybe my way works, but is wrong. Maybe I should be using `.Equals` instead of `==`.

```
private void OpcVariable_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var opcVariable = sender as IAlsVariable;
    var key = m_operatorAudibleSevServerVariables.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == opcVariable).Key;
    UpdateAlarmSound(key, Convert.ToInt32(opcVariableVtqValue));            
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does indeed work as it is. One improvement could be wrapping the `PropertyChanged` event information in a new custom `event` and a new `EventArgs` of your own and have the `Name` and the `opcVariable` instance part of that event. This way you avoid any casting that can lead to runtime error.

Here is an example of the `EventArgs`:

```
public class YourEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Name {get;set;}

    public int OpcVariableVtqValue  {get;set;}

    // If you still need it.
    public string PropertyName {get;set;}
}
```

Here are the changes to done in IAlsVariable:

```
public interface IAlsVariable
{
    event EventHandler<YourEventArgs> YourEvent;
}
```

Now change the implementation:

```
public class SomeAlsVariableImpl : IAlsVariable
{
    public string Name {get;}

    public event EventHandler<YourEventArgs> YourEvent;

    //  Call this method any time you need to raise the event.
    private void RaiseYourEvent(int opcVariableVtqValue)
    {
        YourEvent?.Invoke(this, new YourEventArgs 
        {
             Name = Name,
             OpcVariableVtqValue = opcVariableVtqValue,
        }
    }
}
```

Now, in your main class, you need to subscribe to the following event:

```
        foreach (var clusterManager in clusterManagers)
        {
            var clusterName = clusterManager.Name;
            string opcDataSourceServer = "server/" + clusterName + ":[2:http://www.alstom.com/Transport/Iconis/S2K/Data]<Organizes>2:S2KServer<Organizes>2:S2KTerritoryMngt<Organizes>2:TASSObject<HasComponent>2:OperatorAudibleSev";
            var opcVariable = m_alsApplication.Database.GetVariable(opcDataSourceServer, null);
            opcVariable.YourEvent += OpcVariable_YourEvent;
            m_operatorAudibleSevServerVariables.Add(clusterManager.Name, opcVariable);                
        }
```

And then:

```
private void OpcVariable_YourEvent(object sender, YourEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateAlarmSound(e.Name, e.OpcVariableVtqValue));            
}
```

Do not forget to unsubscribe from the event when your main class is disposed to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: I would definitely like to improve this, but I'm not an expert in event-based programming. What do you mean a new custom event? How do I wrap the PropertyChanged event?

Comment: @Ray I have updated the answer to include an example of how to raise the event. You will have to figure out what exactly is OpcVariableVtqValue as I am not sure where it is coming from. Hopefully, this answer should give you enough to work with :)